# c# - Adding or subtracting a value according to the boolean for each List Item

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Well, I will explain what I'm trying to do.
I have a List for my purchasers and also a listbox. When I add a purchaser to the listbox, he is also added to the List called Purchasers. In this List, I have a value for the name of the purchaser and a bool to say if he paid or not. See my List and the class for it:

```
public class Purchaser
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool Paid { get; set; }
}

List<Purchaser> Purchasers = new List<Purchaser>();
```

Now I will explain what I'm planning to do: all the purchasers must pay $5. I have a checkbox called **box_Paid** and when I check or uncheck it, the variable **paid** is turned in true or false for the actual selected purchaser in my listbox.
I have a limit in the listbox for the purchasers: 14 in total, and a value in one label called **label_AmountLeft** that is 70$.
70/14 = 5$. Each purchaser needs to pay 5$. What I need now is, when I turn the variable for determinate purchaser using the **box_Paid.CheckedChanged** event, the label with the value 70 decreases 5 units. Example, I've checked my checkbox when purchaser Tom is selected in the listbox. The Tom's variable **paid** value now will be **true** and the value of the **label_AmountLeft** will now be 65. I check now for Dylan, the value goes to 60. If I uncheck the textbox for Tom, the values goes to 65, because Dylan's variable **paid** is **true**. If I uncheck the checkbox for both purchasers, the variables will be **false** and the **label_AmountLeft** value will return to 70.
I was trying using:

```
double a, b = 5, rest;
private void box_Paid_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (box_Paid.Checked == true)
    {
        Purchaser p = Purchasers[listDOF.SelectedIndex];
        p.Paid = true;
        a = System.Convert.ToDouble(label_AmountLeft.Text);
        rest = a - b;
        label_AmountLeft.Text = System.Convert.ToString(rest);
    }
    else
    {
        Purchaser p = Purchasers[listDOF.SelectedIndex];
        p.Paid = false;
        a = System.Convert.ToDouble(label_AmountLeft.Text);
        rest = a + b;
        label_AmountLeft.Text = System.Convert.ToString(rest);
    }
}
```

But this do not worked. I think this issue is hard to understand, but I hope someone is able to help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see the `p` variable being used anywhere. Shouldn't you be using `ListBox.SelectedItem` or something? Can you post the code where you initialize the list?

Comment: In the `else` block, you don't set `p.Paid` equal to false. 

The math portion appears correct (if a little odd, you shouldn't store state in controls).

What exactly is wrong?

Comment: @Groo the variable is being used for check the checkbox in my listbox ***listDOF_SelectedIndexChanged*** event.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I messed up to paste the code here. Updated the topic, I have the paid variable turned to false if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: @Hypister: ok, this makes more sense. `new Purchaser` made no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were updating your list properly, then the sum could simply be calculated using:

```
var sum = Purchasers.Where(p => p.Paid).Count() * 5;
```

Or, you could have a separate field for the sum to avoid parsing the text box value each time:

```
// oh, and btw, don't use double when working with money
private decimal _sum;
private void box_Paid_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (box_Paid.Checked == true)
    {
        _sum += 5;
    }
    else
    {
        _sum -= 5;
    }

    label_AmountLeft.Text = _sum.ToString();
}
```

But the weird thing is that you're not updating items from your original list at all, but instead creating new `Purchaser` instances each time (which are collected as soon as you return from the event handler).

So, I am guessing the code should look something like:

```
private void box_Paid_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    // get the currently selected item
    var selectedPurchaser = Purchasers[listDOF.SelectedIndex];

    // set its state
    selectedPurchaser.Paid = box_Paid.Checked;

    // calculate the sum and display it
    UpdateSum();
}

private void UpdateSum()
{
    // calculate the paid sum
    var paidSum = Purchasers.Where(x => x.Paid).Count() * 5;

    // get the amount left
    var amountLeft = 70 - paidSum;

    // update the text box (using whatever formatting you prefer)
    label_AmountLeft.Text = string.Format("${0:0.00}", amountLeft);
}
```

Comment: I'm having an error in the Purchasers.Where(***p*** =>
"A local variable named 'p' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'p', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else."

Comment: Thank you Groo, but now I have the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' in Purchasers.Where(x => x.Paid).Count() * 5;

Comment: Convert it to a string then? Using .toString()

Comment: @Hypister: sorry, I was typing this and doing something else without thinking. Sure, as @Dan wrote, it needs to be converted to a `string` (like you were doing in your original code).

Comment: @Hypister: I updated it, it's just the part where you assign the string representation of the sum to the text box. Which part of the code don't you understand? There are two major differences: 1) there is no need to use an `if` like you're doing, since both branches are pretty much the same. So you can simply set the `Checked` value. And 2) I am using LINQ `Where` to filter items where `Paid` is true, and then `Count` to count them (and multiply this by 5). This is much simpler and less error prone than keeping the sum and incrementing or decrementing it.

Comment: @Hypister: Also, I wouldn't recommend 1) using `double` when working with money, 2) using hardcoded values (5 bucks, 14 items, 70$ total, all of these shouldn't be fixed).

Comment: Hey, thanks! I did not know this method, thanks to add this to my knowledge! Well, it seems we are in the right way, but I need the value to decrease. If I check the box_Paid, according to the selected purchaser in the listDOF, I need to remove 5 from 70.

Comment: Now I'm beginning to understand your code better...
Well, actually is increasing by 5, 10, 15.
There is a way to decrease from 70, 65, 60?
And the label is only updated when I check the item.

Comment: Sure, either count items where `Paid` is `false`, or subtract the `sum` I gave you from 70. I.e. 70 - 5 = 65, which you are looking for. I've updated the answer with the first approach. You probably want to call the `UpdateSum` method when you fill the list, to get the initial sum displayed properly.

Comment: I think the UpdateSum() will be more efficient in the listDOF_SelectedIndexChanged event. I still can not get the value to be subtracted from 70.

Comment: Yes, you need to call it each time inside the handler, but also the first time then you fill the list. Are you sure you used the last code? Where `x.Paid == false`?

Comment: Yes, it seems all is Ok now, except by the decrease count. This continues increasing 5, 10, 15. Need to be 70, 65, 60...

Comment: @Hypister: but what are the initial values in the array? Are they all set to false? If yes, the first call to `UpdateSum` must calculate 70, because all items are matched and counted. Try to understand how the algorithm works, it doesn't help you much if you copy the code without fully understanding it.

Comment: I am not able to understand how your code works in this part. Where 70 is stored?

Comment: If `Purchasers.Count()` is `14`, then multiplying it with `5` should give `70` (presuming that they all have `Paid` set to **`false`**). If **half** of them are selected, then `Purchasers.Where(x => !x.Paid).Count()` should return `7`, and the sum would be `35`. If you set all their `Paid` properties to true, then the count will be zero.

Comment: Now I saw what is wrong. The limit 14 is for the listbox, not for the List. There is no a way to set sum to 70 and go decreasing when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: Sure, that's the other approach I mentioned (subtract the paid sum from 70).

Comment: I did what you said, I analyzed your code better and understand the algorithm and now worked great.
Thank you for spending your time helping me and giving me a bit more of experience in C#, reducing my ignorance.
One more step taken towards knowledge. A great hug!